# Are there disadvantages to `return cb()` in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

Frequently I see (and sometimes write) code that looks like:

```
 var foo = function(someOption, cb){
    // handle some edge case where we don't need to do anything
    if ( someOption === 'whatever' ) {
        return cb(null)
    }
    ...do things...
    cb(result)
}
```

rather than:

```
var foo = function(someOption, cb){
    // handle some edge case where we don't need to do anything
    if ( someOption === 'whatever' ) {
        cb(null)
        return; 
    }
    ...do things...
    cb(result)
}
```

The return value of the function isn't used, the `return` just ends the function early.

Are there any disadvantages or advantages of either approach?

Comment: The first makes me think the return value is something useful.

Comment: if you want to use the return value of the function cb then its required, but after seeing your implementation, its seems like you are not going to use the value

Answer (score 0):

For me it's not totally the same because 
in the first case if cb is a function foo return the result of the function cb.

whereas in the second case 
the function foo call the function cb but return nothing `return`